# Laravel 5.2 PHP 7.0.8 Upgrade Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I am working on a **Laravel 5.2** environment and after some tests I decided to upgrade my PHP version from PHP 5.6.* to 7.0.8 over Ubuntu.

So, I did it by using **phpbrew** and now `php artisan migrate` is not working anymore:

> **[PDOException]**
>     could not find driver

Maybe I should try a downgrade to PHP 5.6 again, or rollback. So, any suggestions?

Comment: You need to let us know what database you are using. (mysql/pgsql/mssql etc...) 
it is very likely you will need to run 'sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql' but that will depend on the database you are running. I am assuming its mysql.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue, tryed dump-autolad, clear-compiled but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: My MySQL version is **5.5.49**. I am using [C9](https://c9.io/) to work with this

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me so far is to disable **MYSQL** strict mode.

I've gone through [this link](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/how-to-disable-mysql-strict-mode-on-laravel-forge-ubuntu) and added the below line on my.cnf.

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=''
```

I don't know if this is a good solution but it helped me to get going.

Comment: There is no section in my MySQL configuration file. This line doesn't exist in _/etc/mysql/my.cnf_: `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Comment: If it doesn't exists then manually add the above code for [mysqld] at the end.